# IE.Navigate syntax with URL and port as variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

What's the correct syntax for IE.Navigate if I want to use the url and port as variables?

Comment: Hi, please read up on this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752093(v=vs.85).aspx) on the Navigate Method.  If you want someone to assist with your code, please post what you have already attempted.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for tips on how to properly ask questions that have a better change of receiving a positive and helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you found an answer yet, but take a look at this and see if it helps

```
Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
myUrl = "http://www.something.com"
myPort = "8080"
    With ie
    .Visible = True
    .AddressBar = False
    .Toolbar = False
    .FullScreen = False
    .Navigate url:= myUrl & ":" & myPort

    While .ReadyState < 4 Or .Busy:  DoEvents:  Wend
```